# Lisp sort function key

Tags: sorting, key, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists

I'm trying to sort a list that looks something like this:

```
(defvar my-list '((:x 1 :y something) (:x 5 :y something) (:x 19 :y something)))
```

I'm trying to sort it by the value in `:x`. I could do that like this

```
(sort my-list #'> :key #'second)
```

but I would very much prefer to use the `getf` function instead of `second`, but I can't figure out how to pass `:x` as a parameter.

From what I can gather just `#'getf` returns `(getf ((:x 1 :y something) '(:x 5 :y something) (:x 19 :y something)) [external]`. How would I go about passing `:x` as the second parameter?

The only way I could think of is to create a wrapper-function for `getf`, which only takes a list as a parameter and passes in `:x` by default. There must be a better way though.

Comment: You don't need to quote the sublists inside a quoted list. Also, you shouldn't use destructive operations like `SORT` on quoted (literal) lists. You can use `COPY-LIST` (or `COPY-TREE`) to make a copy of the list before sorting. For the problem itself, making a wrapper function is the usual solution. That is commonly known as currying. The [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) library has functions `CURRY` and `RCURRY` for it.

Comment: @jkiiski, I don't know what happened there with quotes, you're completely  right. As for the solution itself: you're probably right as well, but I'll hold off on declaring this solved, just in case there's a better (by which I mean more eloquent) solution.

Comment: One alternative would be to use structs (possibly with `(:type list)`), in which case you can use the accessor for the slot.

Comment: a short lambda provided by [cl21](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/cl21.html#shorter-lambda) is rather handy IMO: `(sort *my-list* #'> :key ^(getf % :x))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The is no better way than [`lambda`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ac.htm):

```
(defvar *my-list* '((:x 1 :y something) (:x 5 :y something) (:x 19 :y something)))
(sort *my-list* #'> :key (lambda (plist) (getf plist :x)))
==> ((:X 19 :Y SOMETHING) (:X 5 :Y SOMETHING) (:X 1 :Y SOMETHING))
```

You might be looking for [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), but Common Lisp does not have that OOTB.

[Rainer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285983/850781)'s answer offers ad hoc currying.

Comment: and a shorter version with [cl21](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/cl21.html): `(sort *my-list* #'> :key ^(getf % :x))` :)

Answer (score 8):

If using a property as a key is common in your Lisp code, then you can define a function to create the key function. See the use of `property-key-fn`.

```
CL-USER 22 > (defparameter *my-list* (copy-list '((:x 1  :y foo)
                                                  (:x 5  :y bar)
                                                  (:x 19 :y baz))))
*MY-LIST*

CL-USER 23 > (defun property-key-fn (property)
               (lambda (plist)
                 (getf plist property)))
PROPERTY-KEY-FN

CL-USER 24 > (setf *my-list* (sort *my-list* #'> :key (property-key-fn :x)))
((:X 19 :Y BAZ) (:X 5 :Y BAR) (:X 1 :Y FOO))

CL-USER 25 > (setf *my-list* (sort *my-list* #'string> :key (property-key-fn :y)))
((:X 1 :Y FOO) (:X 19 :Y BAZ) (:X 5 :Y BAR))
```

Comment: When I find myself doing this a lot, I use something like property-key-fn but shorten the name to =getf.